# How to print an array of strings without brackets, so it can be used in a function parameter

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, function, loops

I created a function that takes 4 parameters. But I have 100 different set of these 4 parameters that I want to feed into my function.

Trying to iterate the 100 set with 4 parameter each, but I need the results showing strings only, and not brackets of any type, since my function cannot have additional brackets.

Here is my code:

```
def main():
    run_list = [('file1.csv', 'file2.csv', pd.read_csv('file1.csv').columns[0], pd.read_csv('file2.csv').columns[0]),
                ('file3.csv', 'file4csv', pd.read_csv('file3.csv').columns[0], pd.read_csv('file4.csv').columns[0])]

    for k in run_list:
       myFunction(k)
```

If I break down the code, I get the following:

```
    run_list = [('file1.csv', 'file2.csv', pd.read_csv('file1.csv').columns[0], pd.read_csv('file2.csv').columns[0]),
                ('file3.csv', 'file4csv', pd.read_csv('file3.csv').columns[0], pd.read_csv('file4.csv').columns[0])]

    for k in run_list:
        print(str(k))

>>> ('file1.csv', 'file2.csv', 'column_name1', 'column_name2')
>>> ('file3.csv', 'file4.csv', 'column_name3', 'column_name4')
```

Desired output without brackets, so I can have the 4 parameters from each set to be used in `myFunction` that takes 4 parameters:

```
>>> 'file1.csv', 'file2.csv', 'column_name1', 'column_name2'
>>> 'file3.csv', 'file4.csv', 'column_name3', 'column_name4'
```

I tried `.strip('[]')`, it worked on `print`, but failed on `function`:

```
def main():
    run_list = [('file1.csv', 'file2.csv', pd.read_csv('file1.csv').columns[0], pd.read_csv('file2.csv').columns[0]),
                ('file3.csv', 'file4csv', pd.read_csv('file3.csv').columns[0], pd.read_csv('file4.csv').columns[0])]

    for k in run_list:
       print(k.strip('[]'))

>>> 'file1.csv', 'file2.csv', 'column_name1', 'column_name2'
>>> 'file3.csv', 'file4.csv', 'column_name3', 'column_name4'

def main():
    run_list = [('file1.csv', 'file2.csv', pd.read_csv('file1.csv').columns[0], pd.read_csv('file2.csv').columns[0]),
                ('file3.csv', 'file4csv', pd.read_csv('file3.csv').columns[0], pd.read_csv('file4.csv').columns[0])]

    for k in run_list:
       myFunction(k.strip('[]'))

>>>AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'strip'
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC use `*` for unpack:

```
def myFunction(a,b):
    print (a)
    file1.csv
    file3.csv
    print (b)
    file2.csv
    file4.csv
    return a + '__' + b
    
#test list of tuples
run_list = [('file1.csv', 'file2.csv'),('file3.csv', 'file4csv')]
    
for k in run_list:
    out = myFunction(*k)
    print (out)
    file1.csv__file2.csv
    file3.csv__file4csv
```

If pass tuples:

```
def myFunction(a):
    print (a)
    ('file1.csv', 'file2.csv')
    ('file3.csv', 'file4csv')
    return '__'.join(a)

run_list = [('file1.csv', 'file2.csv', ),
                ('file3.csv', 'file4csv')]
    
for k in run_list:
    out = myFunction(k)
    print (out)
    file1.csv__file2.csv
    file1.csv__file2.csv
```